# ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I've wrapper procedure which looks like this:

```
Procedure A
BEGIN;
    Procedure B
    Procedure C
END;
/
```

Procedure B drops and re-creates a table used in Procedure C. Due to this, I get the below error:

```
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure "SCHEMA.PROCEDURE C" 
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SCHEMA.PROCEDURE C" 
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.PROCEDURE A", line 4 
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How do I go about getting this procedure to work?

Comment: Just run it again and it should be fine. The package state is cached by the session, so if another session changes the body, it invalidates the cache that your session has. This is just Oracle telling you to try again.

Comment: No. Retry does not help.

Comment: there are already a lot of questions about that problem with answers: https://www.google.hu/#q=oracle+ORA-04068+error

Comment: I did check them out, but they didn't solve my problem. I tried to use PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE, but it didn't help since I am not working with packages. Rather just procedures.

Comment: Does the error persist when you recreate procedure c ?

Comment: I'd step back and ask - *why* is procedure B dropping and recreating a table? You shouldn't normally need or want to modify the schema at runtime. If it's a temporary table then it should be created once, outside your procedures, as an actual global temporary table. Then it can just be populated as needed.

Comment: Also, not quite sure how you're getting that error, are all the calls inside the package, or are you calling A, B and C from a block outside the package? If the calls are inside it doesn't seem to error, in 11gr2 anyway, even with a package variable; but does if called externally.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I'm trying to compare data between tables. One table resides in another database. So, the first procedure loads this table into current database & then the second procedure does the comparison. Dropping and re-creating the table is faster than using a DB Link to do the comparison.
Please can you explain a bit more about 'are all the calls inside the package, or are you calling A, B and C from a block outside the package' ?

Comment: Loading a table doesn't mean you need to drop and recreate it though. If you don't want to or can't compare across a DB link you can have a static permanent table that you truncate and repopulate, or a global temporary table that you repopulate, or even an external table - depends how you get the table data from the other DB. Doing DDL at runtime is always going to be painful and overly expensive, and can have side effect (like committing).

Comment: Truncate & re-populate takes longer than dropping and re-creating.

Comment: @collapsar - Yes, I tried recreating the package. It does not help.

Comment: That seems unlikely, as it's doing more work. (Though truncate is also DDL so has some of the same issues; if you're *deleting* and repopulating it would be slower, yes). Anyway, the point was to avoid the situation you have rather than try to work around it.

Comment: have you tried to comment out the line "Procedure B" and execute Procedure A after that?

Comment: @Thomas - I NEED the procedure B!

Comment: @user657592 we know you need proc B, but could u do that? and maybe you could paste in here the code of proc B and proc C too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like it.

```
 begin 
   procedureB;
   begin 
     execute immediate 'begin procedureC; end;';
   exception when others then 
     execute immediate 'begin procedureC; end;';
   end;   
 end;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I think there are too many errors. You can catch ORA-06508, but catching that or others, the next call (in the exception handler) still gets the same stack of errors.

Comment: I have tried it on my db. And it is working. But from other hand i know it very very dirty workaround.

Comment: Accepting your answer as this is the simplest solution for my problem. I agree that this is a dirty hack, but, I need this temporarily and this'll have to do. Thanks!

Comment: using an `exception when others` blindly, without re-raising or rolling back, is dangerous. I believe this is known as "Tom Kyte's Dispair".

Answer (score 2):

So your proc get invalid during the execution, that is why you need recompile Procedure C. To achive this, you can call a dynamic SQL statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PROCEDURE my_procedure COMPILE';



Procedure_A IS
BEGIN;
    Procedure_B;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PROCEDURE Procedure_C COMPILE';
    Procedure_C;
END;
/
```

Comment: You have to compile the package, not the procedure; but that does seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using dynamic SQL to call the DML in procedure C.  By removing the dependency nothing gets invalidated.  This would likely be more reliable than dynamically re-compiling code or dynamically running the code and catching all exceptions.

You can see this in the below sample code.  Comment out the static SQL call on line 10 in procedure C to replicate the error.

```
drop table drop_me;
create table drop_me(id number);

create or replace procedure C is
    v_count number;
begin
    --Static SQL would fail with this error:
    --  ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
    --  ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure "JHELLER.C"
    --  ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "JHELLER.C"
    --  ORA-06512: at "JHELLER.A", line 4
    --  ORA-06512: at line 2
    --select count(*) into v_count from drop_me;

    --Dynamic SQL runs correctly:
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from drop_me' into v_count;
end;
/
create or replace procedure B is
begin
    execute immediate 'drop table drop_me purge';
    execute immediate 'create table drop_me(id number)';
end;
/
create or replace procedure A is
begin
    B;
    C;
end;
/
begin
    A;
end;
/
```

But I agree with Alex Poole that there is almost certainly a better way to do this without dropping and re-creating objects.  I can think of a few reasons why a `DROP` and `CREATE` might run faster than a `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT`, but only because of some weird side-effect, like dropping bad table statistics.  Investigate the difference more and you might find the real reason.